# Is there a way to isolate HTML content for styling when there is no way to adjust the HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Billing Name</strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am unable to edit the HTML here- I am using a "CMS" called Luminate Online, which, when I create something like an event or survey through the tool, it automatically formats everything very horribly. I have to go back in and style everything manually using their classes/ids etc. However, sometimes things don't have classes or ids or anything I can grab on to to style. Like the above, I want to style the words "Billing Name" but I can't figure out how to isolate JUST this (because if I style the td tags or strong tags it would obviously style ALL td or strong tags which I don't want).

Is there some way to use the words "Billing Name" to isolate this in CSS for styling?

If there's not a way using CSS, would someone so very kindly be able to show me the JS or jQuery I could use? I am not experienced in those so it's hard for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: Is it always the first td? `table tr td:first-of-type { /* your styles */ }`

Comment: No, can't target the tag by its content value

Comment: You can maybe look for some other element further up in the DOM that does have an id?

Comment: You could use JS to add inline css.

Comment: I am assuming you have a bunch of these and you cannot simply target by first-child or nth-child right?

Comment: You need to find the combination of selectors that uniquely identifies that text. Without knowing the exact circumstances, we can guess, but that's all it will be. For instance, you could use `table[border="0"][cellspacing="4"][cellpadding="0"] > tr:first-child > td[colspan="3"] > strong`, but as far as I know, you have five tables on your page with those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector:

```
table[cellspacing='4'] tr > td[colspan='3'] > strong { ... }
```

I wouldn't use the `tbody` selector since I am not sure if really *every* browser inserts it automatically. That's also the reason that I didn't put a `>` between `table` and `tr`, since that way it will also apply if a `tbody` is present.

In addition, you can add any classes that exist, and before that, you could even add higher level elements. Another way to get more specific are `:nth-child` and/or `:nth-of-type` selectors, which in your particular example you could add to `tr`,  `td` and`strong`